# Построить графики на одном полотне, где столбцы графика - уникальные значения одного столбца фрейма, а строки - значения другого столбца

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, визуализация

Есть датафрейм со столбцами `Date`, `Type`, `Location` и `Price`. Нужно построить графики (каждый - на отдельной картинке) зависимости `Price` от `Date` для каждого `Type` и всё это - в зависимости от `Location`. То есть на каждом графике должна быть зависимость `Price` от `Date` для каждого `Type`, при этом все графики для каждой из `Location` должны быть сгруппированы в отдельные столбцы.
У меня есть код, который выводит необходимые графики в один столбец, то есть без учета `Location`.

```
dat = pd.read_csv('ap-northeast-1.csv', parse_dates = True, names=['Date','Type','OS', 'Location', 'Price'])
da = dat[dat.OS == 'Windows']
del da['OS']
del da['Location']
date = []
for d in da["Date"]:
    d = str(d)
    date.append(d[:10])
da["Date"] = date
df = da.loc[da.Type.str.startswith('i')]
(df
 .set_index("Date")
 .groupby(['Type','Location'])
 .apply(lambda x: x[["Price"]].plot(grid=True, \
                                    title=[x.name], \
                                    subplots=True)))
```

Всего получается 20 графиков. Полученные 20 графиков необходимо разделить по столбцам в зависимости от того, к какой `Location` эти графики относятся. Всего в столбце `Location` два значения, это `ap-northeast-1a` и `ap-northeast-1c`. В качестве иллюстрации я в Paint сгруппировал по 10 графиков соответствующим образом. В результате работы программы должна происходить аналогичная сортировка графиков, только отображение необходимо в два столбика (по числу разных `Location`, которых в данном случае всего два).

Как разделить эти графики по столбцам с учетом `Location`?

[Датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lNZHzYBdYqK_Ip3G-eNNUzcfiLgWDgNE/view?usp=sharing).

[Группа графиков по первому Location](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z3EPGp31W1mKy1UU-DNmX1r7Mmn18H8r/view?usp=sharing)

[Группа графиков по второму Location](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ryBszP9OQQiVYFq13t7DAez0NZDzX8TU/view?usp=sharing)

Что должно получиться в результате обработки датасета
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете набросать эскиз ? Из описания непонятно что значит «всё это - в зависимости от Location»

Comment: Обновил задание, эскизы добавил в ссылки. У меня экран монитора небольшой,  а графики сводил воедино в Paint, поэтому на эскизе графики не в столбик. Добавил описание ниже кода.

Comment: Что значит `Полученные 20 графиков необходимо разделить по столбцам`? Какие столбцы на графике вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Графики должны быть выведены не в один столбец (как происходит сейчас), а по столбцам (колонкам, если так удобнее называть) в соответствии с содержимым столбца *Location* (ap-northeast-1a и ap-northeast-1c.) исходного датасета. Эскиз того, что должно получиться, я добавил в описание вопроса четвертой ссылкой. То есть ap-northeast-1a и ap-northeast-1c - это фактически имена столбцов с соответствующими им графиками.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def my_plot(df, rot=45, **kwargs):
    ncols = df["Location"].nunique()
    nrows = df["Type"].nunique()
    f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, **kwargs)
    for col, loc in enumerate(df["Location"].unique()):
        d = df.query("Location == @loc")
        for row, typ in enumerate(d["Type"].unique()):
            (d
             .set_index("Date")
             .query("Type == @typ")
             [["Price"]]
             .plot(grid=True, rot=rot, ax=axes[row, col], title=f"{loc}, {typ}"))
    plt.tight_layout()

my_plot(df.set_index("Date"), rot=45, figsize=(12,10), sharex=True, sharey=False)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как увеличить расстояние между ними по оси Y, чтобы все даты были видны?

Comment: Не знаю, задайте отдельный вопрос. Этот ответ и так перегружен, по-моему...

Comment: @AndrewTim, попробуйте еще вызвать функцию с параметром: `sharex=False`